# How to implement datetime data in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I want to implement Dynamic timeline tree in Neo4j.

I have Accounts with transactions. Sample Data below

| AC# | Year | Month | Day | Debit | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2019 | Mar | 01-03-2019 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 123456 | 2020 | Apr | 01-04-2020 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 123456 | 2020 | May | 01-05-2020 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 123457 | 2018 | Jan | 01-01-2018 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 123457 | 2021 | Mar | 01-03-2021 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 123458 | 2017 | Jan | 01-01-2017 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 123458 | 2021 | Mar | 01-03-2021 | 1000 | 1000 |

If the users clicks on any account number, `Year` node should open and on clicking `Year` node, `Month` nodes should open and so on.

`Year` and `Month` nodes should be dynamic. This means if some year is not available for an account number it should not be displayed.

Please help

Comment: You mention "click", "display"... what Graphical User Interface are you referring to? Your own? Neo4j Browser? Not sure what you're asking, it seems you've got the data model already figured out.

Comment: Its in Neo4J.... Yes data model is more or less completed, but how to visualize this data is my question?

Comment: By default in Browser, if your Cypher query returns nodes, you can double-click on them to expand and show their relationships.
Once the data set is imported, all you need is to run a query which returns specific accounts.